# Docker port fowarding working on IPv6 but not IPv4

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, portforwarding

I have the following very simple docker-compose.yml, running on a Mac:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  apache:
    image: httpd:2.4.41
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

I run `docker-compose up`, then I run this `curl` and Apache returns content:

```
/tmp/test $ curl -v http://localhost
*   Trying ::1:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.66.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sat, 26 Oct 2019 18:30:03 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Unix)
< Last-Modified: Mon, 11 Jun 2007 18:53:14 GMT
< ETag: "2d-432a5e4a73a80"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 45
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

However, if I try to access the container using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, I get connection refused:

```
/tmp/test $ curl -v http://127.0.0.1
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
```

Localhost does point to 127.0.0.1:

```
/tmp/test $ ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
```

And netstat shows all local IP addresses port 80 to be forwarded:

```
/tmp/test $ netstat -tna | grep 80
...
tcp46      0      0  *.80                   *.*                    LISTEN     
...
```

I came to this actually trying to access the container using a custom domain I had on my `/etc/hosts` file pointing to 127.0.0.1. I thought there was something wrong with that domain name, but then I tried 127.0.0.1 and didn't work either, so I'm concluding there is something very basic about docker I'm not doing right.

Why is `curl http://localhost` working but `curl http://127.0.0.1` is not?

**UPDATE**

It seems localhost is resolving to IPv6 `::1`, so port forwarding seems to be working on IPv6 but not IPv4 addresses. Does that make any sense?

**UPDATE 2**

I wasn't able to fix it, but pointing my domain name to `::1` instead of `127.0.0.1` in my `/etc/hosts` serves as a workaround for the time being.

**UPDATE 3**

8 months later I bumped into the same issue and found my own question here, still unanswered. But this time I can't apply the same workaround, because I need to bind the port forwarding to my IPv4 address so it can be accessed from other hosts.

Comment: Run curl to provide more useful information: "curl -i -v http://localhost" and "curl -i -v http://127.0.0.1"

Comment: @AlejandroVisiedoGarcía thanks to your comment, I added `-v` and then I noticed localhost is resolving to IPv6 ::1 instead of 127.0.0.1. So it seems docker is forwarding the ports only on the host IPv6.

Comment: hey @Seb I just tried your docker-compose on my mac and is worked perfectly for both `curl http://localhost` and `curl http://127.0.0.1` ‍♀️

Comment: Thank you, @EfratLevitan. That's exactly what I would expect, I'm not sure what I'm missing...

Comment: @Seb try using "network_mode: host" instead of "ports" , then try again, if it doesnt  fix your issue, let me know for more inspecting.

Comment: Still running into this issue 8 months later, maybe this will help somebody (not me yet!): https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2174#issuecomment-289049493

Answer (score 4):

Found the culprit: `pfctl`

AFAIK, `pfctl` is not supposed to run automatically but my `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist` said otherwise.

The Packet Filtering was configured to redirect all incoming traffic on port 80 to 8080, and 443 to 8443. And this is done without any process actually listening to port 80 and 443, that's why `lsof` and `netstat` wouldn't show anything,.

`/Library/LaunchDaemons/it.winged.httpdfwd.plist` has the following

```
 <key>ProgramArguments</key>
 <array>
  <string>sh</string>
  <string>-c</string>
  <string>echo "rdr pass proto tcp from any to any port {80,8080} -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080" | pfctl -a "com.apple/260.HttpFwdFirewall" -Ef - &amp;&amp; echo "rdr pass proto tcp from any to any port {443,8443} -> 127.0.0.1 port 8443" | pfctl -a "com.apple/261.HttpFwdFirewall" -Ef - &amp;&amp; sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1</string>
 </array>
 <key>RunAtLoad</key>
```

The solution was simply to listen on ports 8080 and 8443. All requests to ports 80 and 443 are now being redirected transparently.

While debugging this I found countless open questions about similar problems without answers. I hope this helps somebody.